# How to eliminate last character in a java string

Tags: java

I need to eliminate the last character of the string of 's'

I have tried to use a variable to have it set to the last character and used that variable to put it in the parameters of the subscript but I get an error when doing so.

```
public static void noLast(String s){
char last = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
System.out.println(s.substring(0,last));
```

`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 108, length 5`

This is the error I get when I put the string variable as 'hello' and try to eliminate the 'o'

Comment: Check the javadoc of the method [`String.substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). You need to pass the indexes not characters

Comment: Try if(s.length()> 0)System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length()-1)

Answer (score 5):

All you need is

```
System.out.println(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
```

There is no need to actually fetch the last character.

Answer (score 1):

**Signature of String.substring**

```
substring(beginIndex,lastIndex)
```

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

So, if you put character in parameter, it converted `'l'` into ASCII code `108` automatically that's why you got `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` at end 108.

So, just use like that -

```
System.out.println(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
```

Comment: How it is differer from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720820/2767755) ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit because this one explains the issues before giving a solution ...

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a regex approach:

```
String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
System.out.println(input);
input = input.replaceAll(".$", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

This prints:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy do
```

Note that in practice the substring option would be more efficient, and probably is what you would want to use in production.  But regex can also handle this requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of getting the last character just get the last index

```
int last = s.length() - 1;
```

Modify like this

```
public static void noLast(String s){
    int last = s.length() - 1;
    System.out.println(s.substring(0,last));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use substring method.

```
String str = "stackoverflow";
System.out.println(str.substring(0,str.length-1);
```

will print `stackoverflo`. Eliminating the last character.

Substring method takes in parameter the begin index and end index.

Comment: How it is differer from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720820/2767755) ?